# GLSL access coverage mask of sampler2D texel

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, antialiasing, multisampling

If I access a multisample texture in GLSL through a sampler2DMS, how do I know which of the samples in a texel of this multisample texture have actually been covered?

From the multisample extension reference:
"... Each pixel fragment thus consists of integer x and y grid coordinates, a color, SAMPLES_ARB depth values, texture coordinates, and a coverage value with a maximum of SAMPLES_ARB bits."

So what I would like to access is the coverage value of the texel. There is gl_SampleMask (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_SampleMask.xhtml) that I can use to WRITE the coverage value of the FRAGMENT currently processed, but how do I access the coverage value of the TEXEL I'm fetching from the multisample texture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea with multisampling is that, when you render to a multisampled image, you only execute the fragment shader once for each pixel-sized area. The rasterizer-generated coverage mask determines which samples within the pixel the fragment's outputs go to.

But once that process is done, once the fragment shader writes its data, the multisample image *itself* has absolutely no idea what these coverage masks are. A multisample texture simply has multiple sample values per texel. It has no idea what fragments generated which samples with which sample masks.

Sample masks are only a part of rendering.

Think of it like this. This is a multisample texture's pixel:

```
vec4 pixel[SAMPLE_COUNT];
```

Your fragment shader, when you were rendering to the multisample texture, did the equivalent of this:

```
for(int sample_ix = 0; sample_ix < SAMPLE_COUNT; ++sample_ix)
{
  if(sampleMask[sample_ix])
    pixel[sample_ix] = output;
}
```

`pixel`'s data may have originally come from a sample mask. But `pixel` has no idea that this happens; it's just an array of `vec4` values.

You can get the coverage value of your *current* fragment. But that has no relation to the actual coverage value(s) used to originally compose the pixels in a multisample texture.

Comment: Thank you Nicol, this is a very clear and understandable explanation! As a related question, is it instead possible to easily (without iterating) check whether or not the samples of a texel in a multisampled texture are all the same or not?

Comment: @user1282931: Nope ;) It'd be nice, though, but they just don't store that information.